# Customizing File Input

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to upload file with customization?

```
<%= f.file_field :image, class: 'inputfile' %>
<label for="image">Choose an image</label>
```

I want to place "choose an image" with "choose a file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You javascript is missing the logic to get the chosen file name as the tutorial:

```
var fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();
```

So your javascript will be updated to:

```
input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e ) {
  var inspiration_image = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();
  if( inspiration_image ) {
    label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = inspiration_image;
  } else {
    label.innerHTML = labelVal;
  }
});
```

**Update with full code**

```
<%= file_field_tag :image, class: 'inputfile' %>
<label for="inspiration_image">Choose a file</label>

<script>
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
  Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input ) {
    var label  = input.nextElementSibling,
      labelVal = label.innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e ) {
        var fileName = '';
        if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 ) {
            fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
        } else {
            fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();
        }

        if( fileName ) {
            label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
        } else {
            label.innerHTML = labelVal;
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry Hieu that didn't work. You think I put the `inspiration_image` in the right spots when I replaced the tutorials `file` and `files`? Full html of file input: `<input class="inputfile" type="file" name="inspiration[image]" id="inspiration_image"> <label for="inspiration_image">Choose a file</label>`

Comment: I'm not sure, let update you question with the current problem & what is the expected result?

Comment: Current problem is same as before, which is the "Choose an image" text hasn't changed to the name of the file chosen after a file is chosen, which is the expected result. Sorry idk if that clarification was helpful.

Comment: `inspiration_image` is in incorrect spot, because it will always assign to '' (empty) and `else` block was always run !, btw, I didn't see anywhere you put the logic to get the file name, did you try my suggestion to get that file name?

Comment: What's the correct spot? I copy and pasted your code in and the problem in the question persisted. I tried your code in your answer if that's what you mean by "try my suggestion to get that file name"?

Comment: Hmm, when you try it, any issue? I just tested on my project, it worked. Back to the root issue, your problem is in the logic or the way to get file name?

Comment: Hmm well for file name I used the id. `id="inspiration_image"`. Otherwise what did you put for the name that made it work? We are so close then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104063/discussion-between-hieu-pham-and-anthonygalli-com).

Comment: Hi Hieu! Did you mean to use the same exact code in your answer as the tutorial for the javascript section in your updated answer or was that a mistake? Thanks for your help regardless

Comment: I know you were on little sleep :)